# How to create Kafka Stream that reads from one topic and writes to another

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I have `INPUT_TOPIC` in Kafka that gets data published by some Kafka Connector.

I want to take this data and push it to another Kafka topic, called `OUTPUT_TOPIC`.

First I go ahead and create a `STREAM_A` that reads data from `INPUT_TOPIC`. It will have two fields I am interested in: the `timestamp` and `dimension`:

```
CREATE STREAM STREAM_A (`timestamp` BIGINT, DIMENSION STRUCT<HEIGHT BIGINT, WIDTH BIGINT>) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'INPUT_TOPIC', PARTITIONS=6, VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON');
```

After `STREAM_A` was created I see that it is receiving the data from `INPUT_TOPIC`.

Since I want this data to be written to a second `OUTPUT_TOPIC` I create a second stream `STREAM_B` that `SELECT FROM STREAM_A` and writes to `OUTPUT_TOPIC`:

```
CREATE STREAM STREAM_B WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='OUTPUT_TOPIC') AS SELECT `timestamp`, DIMENSION FROM STREAM_A;
```

It works as is. But there are now two streams to deal with. I wonder if instead of creating two streams `STREAM_A` and `STREAM_B` I could create a single stream that would read the data from `INPUT_TOPIC` and write to `OUTPUT_TOPIC`

Is there a way to create such stream or I would have to have two streams?
Would it be possible to consolidate two streams into one so this consolidated stream reads data from `INPUT_TOPIC` and writes to `OUTPUT_TOPIC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STREAM_A` provides a namespace to query `INPUT_TOPIC`

`STREAM_B` is a derived stream that queries against `STREAM_A`, and there is no other operator for "copy topic to topic" (as bytes) in KSQL. Although, `SELECT * FROM` may work, in theory, rather than giving every field.

Note: If you simply want to copy one topic into another without any projection operation [or to update partitions/replication](https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/change-topic-partitions-replicas/ksql.html), then IMO you'd be wasting space on the cluster, but you could just do the same with simply `kStream.stream("input-topic").to("output-topic")` in a JVM app, or use alternative methods like MirrorMaker.

Comment: Would it be possible to copy a streaming data from one topic to another using a single ksql statement?

Comment: No. As mentioned, you need to create a stream to run a `CREATE STREAM AS SELECT (CSAS)` statement. But again, [MirrorMaker would be the recommended tool for such a pattern](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/connect/mirror), which, yes, can be ran in one command.